# STM32 HAL C QuadSPI Display read and write

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, spi

I am using QSPI not to connect memory, but a FTDI display.
I used STM32CubeMX and Atollic TrueStudio. I included FreeRTOS, but I'm not using that, yet.

Using QuadSPI, I have trouble to read and write 1, 2 or 4 bytes, where I transmit a 3 byte memory address.

If I try to read an address like this, it times out at HAL_QSPI_Receive, and no signals are generated on the bus, if I configure

```
s_command.AddressMode    = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
```

If I configure

```
s_command.AddressMode    = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
```

Signals are generated to read a byte, but the address is not send of course.

To send the address and receive bytes afterwards, I send the address in the Alternate bytes. But now the number of bytes can 1 or 2, but not 4, because I will get a time-out again.

My code pieces

```
    uint8_t pData[4];
    uint32_t address = REG_ID;
    QspiReadData(address, 1, pData);

        uint32_t v = 0x12345678;
    pData[0] = v >> 24;
    pData[1] = (v >> 16) & 0xff;
    pData[2] = (v >> 8) & 0xff;
    pData[3] = v & 0xff;
        QspiWriteData(addr, 4, pData);

uint8_t QspiReadData(uint32_t address, uint32_t size, uint8_t* pData)
{
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef s_command;
    QSPI_AutoPollingTypeDef s_config;

    /* Initialize the read command */
    s_command.InstructionMode  = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_NONE;
    s_command.Instruction    = 0;
    s_command.AddressMode    = QSPI_ADDRESS_1_LINE;
    s_command.AddressSize    = QSPI_ADDRESS_32_BITS;
    s_command.Address      = address;
    s_command.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
    s_command.AlternateBytes   = 0;
    s_command.AlternateBytesSize = 0;
    s_command.DataMode      = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE; // QSPI_DATA_4_LINES
    s_command.DummyCycles    = 0;
    s_command.NbData       = size;
    s_command.DdrMode      = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    s_command.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    s_command.SIOOMode      = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Configure the command */
    printf("HAL_QSPI_Command\n");
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &s_command, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        printf("HAL_ERROR\n");
        return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Reception of the data */
    printf("HAL_QSPI_Receive\n");
    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(&hqspi, pData, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        printf("HAL_ERROR\n"); // Timeout after 5000mS
        return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    return HAL_OK;
}


/* QUADSPI init function */
void MX_QUADSPI_Init(void)
{

  hqspi.Instance = QUADSPI;
  hqspi.Init.ClockPrescaler = 254; /* 4 QSPI Freq= 108 MHz / (1+4) = 21.6 MHz */
  hqspi.Init.FifoThreshold = 1;
  hqspi.Init.SampleShifting = QSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_NONE;
  hqspi.Init.FlashSize = 0;
  hqspi.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = QSPI_CS_HIGH_TIME_8_CYCLE;
  hqspi.Init.ClockMode = QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0; // QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0 Rising edge CPOL=0, QSPI_CLOCK_MODE_3 Falling edge CPOL=1
  hqspi.Init.FlashID = QSPI_FLASH_ID_1;
  hqspi.Init.DualFlash = QSPI_DUALFLASH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_QSPI_Init(&hqspi) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

uint8_t QspiWriteData(uint32_t address, uint32_t size, uint8_t* pData)
{
    QSPI_CommandTypeDef s_command;

    printf("Ft813QspiReadData8(%ld, %d, pData)\n", address, size);


    /* Initialize the read command */
    s_command.InstructionMode    = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_NONE;
    s_command.Instruction        = 0;
    s_command.AddressMode        = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
    s_command.AddressSize        = QSPI_ADDRESS_24_BITS;
    s_command.Address            = 0;
    s_command.AlternateByteMode  = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_1_LINE;
    s_command.AlternateBytes     = address;
    s_command.AlternateBytesSize = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_24_BITS;
    s_command.DataMode           = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
    s_command.DummyCycles        = 0;
    s_command.NbData             = size;
    s_command.DdrMode            = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
    s_command.DdrHoldHalfCycle   = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
    s_command.SIOOMode           = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;

    /* Configure the command */
    printf("HAL_QSPI_Command\n");
    if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &s_command, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        printf("HAL_ERROR\n");
        return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Reception of the data */
    printf("HAL_QSPI_Transmit\n");
    if (HAL_QSPI_Transmit(&hqspi, pData, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) {
        printf("HAL_ERROR\n");
        return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    return HAL_OK;
}
```

What can be the problem?

---

The GPIO pins were configured like this, in case it helps sombody else:

```
void HAL_QSPI_MspInit(QSPI_HandleTypeDef* qspiHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(qspiHandle->Instance==QUADSPI)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN QUADSPI_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END QUADSPI_MspInit 0 */
    /* QUADSPI clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_QSPI_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**QUADSPI GPIO Configuration    
    PF6     ------> QUADSPI_BK1_IO3
    PF7     ------> QUADSPI_BK1_IO2
    PF8     ------> QUADSPI_BK1_IO0
    PF9     ------> QUADSPI_BK1_IO1
    PF10     ------> QUADSPI_CLK
    PB10     ------> QUADSPI_BK1_NCS 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = QUADSPI_BK1_IO3_Pin|QUADSPI_BK1_IO2_Pin|QUADSPI_CLK_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_QUADSPI;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = QUADSPI_BK1_IO0_Pin|QUADSPI_BK1_IO1_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_QUADSPI;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = QUADSPI_BK1_NCS_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_QUADSPI;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(QUADSPI_BK1_NCS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* QUADSPI DMA Init */
    /* QUADSPI Init */
    hdma_quadspi.Instance = DMA2_Stream2;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_11;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_quadspi.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_quadspi) != HAL_OK)
    {
      _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(qspiHandle,hdma,hdma_quadspi);

    /* QUADSPI interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(QUADSPI_IRQn, 5, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(QUADSPI_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN QUADSPI_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END QUADSPI_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to have posted any code for enabling the I/O banks and putting the relevant I/O pins an SPI alternate function mode.  If you have that, use and edit to include it, if you do not, you'll need to do that properly first before any of this will have external effect.

Comment: Hi Chris, you are right. With the logic analyzer I can see it worked in the limited situations, so I thought it would be a problem elsewhere as gokhannnsahin pointed out below. Anyway, in case it helps somebody else, here it is.

Answer (score 4):

hqspi.Init.FlashSize = 0; is wrong. QuadSPI module needs to learn the memory of device which will write/read. Change it with 31. It will run.

Comment: it works fine now. I have a question though, the value 31, how was that determined?

Comment: @user10155902 If this solved the problem, you should mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the green check mark to the left of this post. Also remember to up-vote all helpful answers!

Comment: For memory devices, the formula is given in of section 13.3.8 of https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00305990-stm32f72xxx-and-stm32f73xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf#page=356 
I've just found that a non-zero but wrong value for the flash size caused a HAL_QPSI_Receive to timeout.